# formatting c++ file with clang-format in vscode doesn´t work

Tags: clang-format

I´m getting the error message:

```
YAML:58:21: error: unknown key 'IncludeIsMainRegex'
IncludeIsMainRegex: '$'

Error reading ~/path/to/c++/project/.clang-format: Invalid argument
```

in vscode when I try to format the cpp file with clang format does anybody how to fix it ?

Comment: I guess that vscode plugin doesn't like the `IncludeIsMainRegex` directive in your `.clang-format` file.

Comment: if you use this plugin https://github.com/xaverh/vscode-clang-format-provider follow this issue https://github.com/xaverh/vscode-clang-format-provider/issues/58. As a quick trial you could remove the directive from you .clang-format and see if can now format also with vscode.

Comment: What is the contents of your `.clang-format` file?  What version of clang-format are you using?